# How to use policial gem in my RoR project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, railstutorial.org

i want to use policial gem in my RoR project. I search in the documentation gem https://github.com/volmer/policial and this is very general. I don't understand where I can instantiate the detective for investigates pull requests and accuses style guide violations in my project.

I search in google i don't find tutorials or examples. Could help me with some example or related information. Thank you.

Comment: Why and how do you want to use the gem in your application? What do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can create [overcommit](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit) gem which creates Github hooks and if you style guide violations you will be prompted to create commits. you can configure overcommit to use various linter and Rubocop. Rubocop is widely accepted ruby linter.